# Windows 10 Narrator. Keyboard short cut. Read document beginning at current cursor

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, narrator

'<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>'
starts Windows 10 Narrator reading from 
the start of the document.

What is the keyboard short cut combination command 
to start Narrator reading 
beginning at the current cursor position ?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

press on keyboard: <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately 
Caps Lock + ] 
does not start Narrator reading 
beginning at the current cursor position

Comment: It works actually but you can also check it yourself 
http://www.ncbi.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Get-started-with-Narrator.doc
CTRL + F and type current cursor you can find it in there